# How to handle invalid routes in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, routes

I am using the following code to handle invalid route.

```
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

This is react app.js code for routing

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./mainPages/home";
import Register from "./components/authentication/register";
import Signin from "./components/authentication/signin";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/authentication/forgotPassword";
import List from "./mainPages/list";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import Details from "./mainPages/details";
import UpdatePassword from "./components/authentication/updatePassword";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "./components/notfound/notfound";
import ResetPassword from "./components/authentication/resetPassword";

function App() {
  

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          component={() => (
            <Home />)}/>
    
        <Route path="*">
          <NotFound />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but It just shows blank page while I want to redirect user to home page using Reactjs.

Comment: This is your server serving a SPA. After the SPA is served, it is the responsibility of the SPA to do proper routing. Show the react routing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code instead. Its working fine

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}`);
});
```